# Keep only one nearest OD link (QNEAT)

Tags: qgis, expression, select-by-attribute, distance-matrix

I've made a distance matrix from one point layer (layer A) to another (layer B) using [QNEAT plugin (QGIS Network Analysis Toolbox 3)](https://root676.github.io/).

I got a web with links from every point from A to every point from B, but I don't need that many links. I need to have unique links from A to B, and once a point from B is taken by any point from A, it cannot be selected for a link.

In other words, I'm looking for a way to filter the data which I got using QNEAT.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do can only work if you have the same number of points in both layers, so I suppose this is the case.

So basically, for each feature of layer A (in QNEAT output referenced with `origin_id`) you want to get a distinct/unique feature of layer B (`destination_id`) linked - as shown in the screenshot, the selected features (marked in blue):

[image]

This can be done selecting the smallest `origin_id` with the smallest `destination_id`, second smallest `origin_id` with second smallest `destination_id` etc. To do so, use [Select by Expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) with this expression:

```
destination_id =
array_get (
    array_sort (
        array_distinct(
            array_agg (destination_id)
        )
    ),
    array_find (
        array_sort (
            array_distinct(
                array_agg (origin_id)
            )
        ), 
        origin_id
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, the 'Join by lines (hub lines)' tool will connect points in A to the nearest point in B. However, as far as I know, there is no tool that ensures that every point in B is assigned to at most one point in A.